# HttpClient.GetStreamAsync stuck

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I use `HttpClient` to make a `GET` request to the API that should return me JSON data but my request is stuck at `GetStreamAsync`. I was debugged it before when it come to `await that.GetStreamAsync(url);` my debugger is gone. Disappear. I try to fixed it for a day but still not work. At first, I think it was my proxy problem, but it isn't. Then, I try to use `HttpRequest` it work fine.

Here is my class.

```
public async Task<bool> RequestToApi(string response)
{
    HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
    if (_cdnResProxy.Value.Length > 0 && _cdnResPort.Value > 0)
    {
        httpClientHandler.Proxy = new WebProxy(string.Format("{0}:{1}",
        _cdnResProxy.Value,
        _cdnResPort.Value))
        { BypassProxyOnLocal = true };
    }

    //try to remove proxy here already but still not work

    using (var hClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
    {
        hClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
        var result = await hClient.Get<ResponseObj>(
             $"https://www.example.com/api/somepath?something={someValue}");

        return result.success;
    }
}

public static class HttpClientExtension
{
    public static async Task<T> Get<T>(this HttpClient that, string url)
    {
        var stream = await that.GetStreamAsync(url); //stuck here
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        T data;
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            data = (T)serializer.Deserialize(streamReader, typeof(T));
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

This's my controller.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [SwaggerVisible]
    [SwaggerOperation("SignIn_VerifyCaptchaAction")]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(bool))]
    public bool RecaptchaSubmit(string response)
    {
        return _service.RecaptchaSubmit(response).Result;
    }
```

This is my `Http`package version :

```
<package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.2" targetFramework="net462" />
```

Here is the method I try already.

```
var stream = await that.GetStreamAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: If `Get()` isn't called in a UI thread, try this. Does that change anything? `var stream = await that.GetStreamAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);`

Comment: @QualityCatalyst I try that before it's not work. I try it again, still not work.

Comment: Any particular reason why you are not using `GetStringAsync` instead?

Comment: Are you using a real url or `https://www.example.com/api/somepath?something={someValue}`? Is `GetStreamAsync` returning 404? Wrap `var stream = await that.GetStreamAsync(url);` in a try/catch. Whats the exception say?

Comment: @garethb It's not break something. So try exception throw nothing. Debugger just gone.

Comment: @Ephraim `GetStringAsync` give me the same problem

Comment: Looks like you did not use async action in the controller class.

Comment: @UltimaWeapon has a point. Mind showing us your controller if it is also running asynchronously?

Comment: @Ephraim I added the controller code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @UltimaWeapon was right, you are not using an async controller thus, everything runs synchronously. As much as possible you have to await all async calls to avoid thread blocks.

```
[HttpPost]
[SwaggerVisible]
[SwaggerOperation("SignIn_VerifyCaptchaAction")]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(bool))]
public async Task<bool> RecaptchaSubmit(string response)
{
    return await _service.RecaptchaSubmit(response);
}
```

Though I am not aware of returning `bool` in the controller. AFAIK returning an `ActionResult` is commonly used. As I do not use this, I cannot comment about it.